# What is the best way to target a FontAwesome Icon using JS and Event Bubbling

Tags: javascript, svg, font-awesome, event-bubbling, font-awesome-5

The new FontAwesome 5 version, while using their "SVG with JS", makes the icons look extremely clean. The side effects is that it is extremely difficult to find a fool-proof way of targeting it using event bubbling/delegation. Sometimes you will click on it and get the `path` node and other times you will get the `svg` node.

I've tried using their way of nesting `svg` inside of an `i` tag and it's not working. They try to explain it here [Auto-Replace-SVG-Nst](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#auto-replace-svg-nest) but... I haven't made any progress.

So I went ahead and manually nest the original `i` that is replaced with another `i`. `<i><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i></i>`. When checking the `event` `console.log(e.target.parentElement)`, I will sometimes get the correct `<i>` and other times I will get the `<svg>`. Which lets me know I am still hitting the `path` and `<svg>`.

Because I am not able to accurately target the correct element, I am getting some extremely unpredictable results. All the content on this page is being dynamically generated either through a PHP query from the DB or AJAX from the DB. Am I supposed to write two different handlers for the same event just to combat this problem?

I realize I can just use the `Web Fonts with CSS` version, but compared to the `JS` version, the icons look really pixelated so I would rather use the `JS` version if possible.

### Notes

I must use event bubbling for this situation because the elements are being generated AFTER the page has loaded.

Comment: Please add your code to the question so we could see why you cannot target the correct element.

Comment: I always use jQuery and closest to target up the chain

Comment: Well no jQuery for this project. So far I have it working with some mixed results by following the `event bubbling path` up the chain. For example `if (e.path[1].nodeName === 'I' && e.path[0].className.baseVal === 'svg-inline--fa fa-comment-alt fa-w-18 fa-lg')` where `e.path[1].nodeName` is the actual `<i>` element, after I got nested icons working, and `e.path[0].className.baseVal` is where you are actually clicking, usually the `<svg>`.